# JQuery not firing for select element

Tags: jquery

I'm writing validation code for form and everything works ok except event is not firing for two select element in the form. There is nothing special about them only that first option in both has value='' and selected disabled attribute.

Can someone tell my whats wrong?

Here is JQuery:

```
var obj = {
    "iname" : {},
    "old_price" : {},
    "discount" : {},
    "category" : {},
    "subcategory" : {},
    "item_image" : {},
    };

$('#form').on("submit", function(){

        var formvalid = true;

        //ON SUBMIT test if input elements have empty value. NOT FIRING FOR SELECT!     
        $.each(obj, function(key){

            if($("#"+key+"").val()==''){
                $("#"+key+"").addClass('form-control');
                $("#"+key+"").parent().addClass('has-error');
                $("#"+key+"").parent().append('<span id="glyph-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
                $("#"+key+"").parent().append('<div class="error-hint-empty alert alert alert-warning"><span class="warning-glyph glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>You must input '+$("#"+key+"").parent().find('label').text()+'!</div>');         
           formvalid = false;               
           }    
});// End of empty value test

return formvalid;
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ML2a4/6/)

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: add it to http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ML2a4/1/

Comment: please share the updated fiddle url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the option is disabled, the select elements value is coming as null not `''` so try

```
    $.each(obj, function (key) {
        var value = $("#" + key + "").val();
        if (value == '' || value == null) {

            $("#" + key + "").addClass('form-control');
            $("#" + key + "").parent().addClass('has-error');
            $("#" + key + "").parent().append('<span id="glyph-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
            $("#" + key + "").parent().append('<div class="error-hint-empty alert alert alert-warning"><span class="warning-glyph glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>You must input ' + $("#" + key + "").parent().find('label').text() + '!</div>');
            formvalid = false;
        }

    }); // End of empty value test
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ML2a4/)

Answer (score 0):

Place an alert in the submit event as following to check if the event is triggered

```
$('#form').on("submit", function(){
    alert('submit invoked')
    var formvalid = true;
    //ON SUBMIT test if input elements have empty value. NOT FIRING FOR SELECT!     
    $.each(obj, function(key){
        if($("#"+key+"").val()==''){
            $("#"+key+"").addClass('form-control');
            $("#"+key+"").parent().addClass('has-error');
            $("#"+key+"").parent().append('<span id="glyph-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
            $("#"+key+"").parent().append('<div class="error-hint-empty alert alert alert-warning"><span class="warning-glyph glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>You must input '+$("#"+key+"").parent().find('label').text()+'!</div>');
            formvalid = false;
        }
    });// End of empty value test
return formvalid;
});
```

This will help you figure out if its the event causing the issue.

Since you have not given the whole html .. check if you have included the jQuery file in the head tag.

Comment: also add the html .. the form that causes the submits